# VP value of space 0 & 1 on the reputation track in Above and Below

Tags: scoring, above-and-below

In Above and Below, the area next to the starting space and the 1-reputation space on the reputation track have a 2/3 and a 5 vp symbol next to them:

[image: Picture of the board, taken from https://twitter.com/bottomshelfbg/status/664084060856283136]

My group has become mixed on whether those symbols are meant to indicate that you get 2 points for the 0-reputation space and 5 points for the 1-reputation space. I was on board until I realized that those matched up to the 1st/2nd place bonuses, and that it might indicate that instead.

As far as I could find, there doesn't seem to be anything in the rules in favor of either case, nor could I find anything online to help. Does anyone know if there's a ruling on this somewhere?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to create a tag for this game, so I picked something that was somewhat relevant. I also couldn't find a "rules-clarification" tag or anything similar, so I went with scoring.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, please take a second to create a tag wiki for [tag:above-and-below] (or ask another question about the game) so the tag doesn't get auto-reaped

Comment: The reason there isn't a "rules-clarification" tag is because 90% of our questions are rules clarifications. Not really worth it to create a tag if so many of our questions cover that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are no reputation points at these positions.**

The 2/3/5 is a reminder for the rank-based scoring of reputation. The smaller numbers are for position-based scoring. There are no bonuses or penalties for being within -1 and +2 reputation.

In the end-of-game scoring, reputation is used for two different point awards. One of these is rank-based, where you get points for having the first or second most reputation. The other is position-based, where you gain (or lose) points based on your individual reputation. In a game where nobody gains or loses much reputation, the ranked points are still relevant. In a game where everyone has high reputation, you'll still get the points from your position regardless of your rank.

From [the rules](https://gesellschaftsspiele.spielen.de/uploads/files/2262/55af56ec28da9.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> ## Reputation
>
> At the end of the game, the player with the most reputation gains 5 extra village points. The player with the second-most reputation gains 3 extra village
>   points. The player with the third-most reputation gains 2 extra village points. If playing with two players, only the player with the most reputation gets the bonus: he gains 3 points (this is why there is a person symbol with the number “2” in this village point symbol).
>
> Players also gain or lose village points **indicated by a smaller village point symbol next to their position on the track**. For example, if a player ended the game with his cube on the highest space on the track, near the surface, he would lose 2 village points.

The 2/3/5 are the larger symbols.